# vcpkg integrate install missing on macOS/Linux

Tags: c++, windows, macos, makefile, vcpkg

The vcpkg helps to manage libraries for C++ projects on Windows/macOS/Linux.

On Windows one can

```
vcpkg integrate install
```

https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/integration/

But outside Windows that does not seem to exist. Am I wrong?

That end up making `CMakeLists.txt` made on Windows not portable to macOS/Linux. While migrating a project from Windows to macOS I found I have to add

```
include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)
```

otherwise make will fail to find header files.

Comment: https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/integration.html#cmake-integration

Comment: In that link it states what the question states in other works "Note that we do not automatically add ourselves to your compiler include paths".

Comment: But vcpkg does modify your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` so that `find_package` calls in your `CMakeLists.txt` are able find required packages. If the required package does not provide exported targets, you should manually call `find_path`/`find_library` and add this path to `target_include_directories`/`target_link_libraries`.